# ng test: [object ErrorEvent] thrown

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-test

I'm using `Angular 6`.

On running

```
ng test
```

I'm getting error like

```
ResetPasswordComponent should create
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
```

In window console, it is giving

Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'auth/login'

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'auth/login'
at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (VM4374 router.js:1455)
at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (VM4374 router.js:1436)
at CatchSubscriber.error (VM4260 catchError.js:40)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (VM4156 Subscriber.js:90)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (VM4156 Subscriber.js:70)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (VM4156 Subscriber.js:90)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (VM4156 Subscriber.js:70)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (VM4156 Subscriber.js:90)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (VM4156 Subscriber.js:70)
at TapSubscriber._error (VM4280 tap.js:67)
at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (VM4374 router.js:1455)
at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (VM4374 router.js:1436)
at CatchSubscriber.error (VM4260 catchError.js:40)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (VM4156 Subscriber.js:90)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (VM4156 Subscriber.js:70)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (VM4156 Subscriber.js:90)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (VM4156 Subscriber.js:70)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (VM4156 Subscriber.js:90)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (VM4156 Subscriber.js:70)
at TapSubscriber._error (VM4280 tap.js:67)
at resolvePromise (VM4143 zone.js:813)
at resolvePromise (VM4143 zone.js:770)
at eval (VM4143 zone.js:872)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM4143 zone.js:420)
at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (VM4148 zone-testing.js:318)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM4143 zone.js:419)
at Object.onInvokeTask (VM4143 zone.js:298)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM4143 zone.js:419)
at Object.onInvokeTask (VM4151 core.js:4109)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (VM4143 zone.js:419)
at
```

I have created `auth` module which has component `ResetPasswordComponent`.

The `AuthModule` is imported in `auth-layout` module and routing is defined in `auth-layout` module.

Contents of `AuthModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    LoginComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent,
    LogoutComponent
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

There is no `auth/login` in the component file.

the **reset-password.component.html** file has line

```
<a routerLink="/auth/login">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably irrelevant to the OP at this point, but for anyone who encounters a similar issue, and for whom none of the provided solutions for [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083089/unhandled-promise-rejection-cannot-match-any-routes) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127925/error-uncaught-in-promise-error-cannot-match-any-routes-url-segment-site/51129273) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44237786/angular-4-unit-test-cannot-read-property-root-of-undefined/44330534) have worked or apply, I'll leave this here.

Like the OP, I had an `[object ErrorEvent] thrown` error in the Jasmine window, and an accompanying error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'members'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'members'
at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError
...
```

Also like the OP, the path referenced in the error *wasn't referenced in the spec or in the component the spec belonged to*.

After several attempts to fix the error I finally decided to disable the spec. The error then moved to the next spec. So I checked the spec and component that ran *immediately before* the one reported as a "failure". Sure enough, in the previous component there was a reference to the path in the error, however its spec didn't register the path in the `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes` call.

**TLDR:**

If you have specs for *FirstComponent*, *SecondComponent* and *ThirdComponent*, but ThirdComponent fails in similar circumstances to those described above, then **check *SecondComponent*** to see if the route is referenced there. If it is, create a stub component, declare it, and add it to your `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes` import with the missing route. e.g.

```
...

describe('SecondComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{path:'missing/path',component:SecondComponent}])
      ],
      declarations: [ SecondComponent ]
    })
  })

  ...

})

@Component({selector:'app-second',template:''})
class SecondComponent {}
```

I hope this saves someone some time. I lost hours on this, mainly because I took the failure report too literally.